# Parse string in json format from Kafka using Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

What I want to do is reading a string in json format e.g.

```
{"a":1, "b":2}
```

using flink and then extract a specific value by its key, say 1.

Refer to here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/connectors/kafka.html

What I have done is:

```
val params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args)
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

val kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010(
  params.getRequired("input-topic"),
  new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false),
  params.getProperties
)

val messageStream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer)
```

But I am not quite sure how to move forward then. In the link above, it says I can use `objectNode.get(“field”).as(Int/String/…)()` to extract a specific value by key, but I wonder how can I do that?

Or there can be a completely different way to achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply data transformation on the data from Kafka like this:

```
messageStream.map(new MapFunction<ObjectNode, Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object map(ObjectNode value) throws Exception {
        value.get("field").as(...)
    }
})
```

Comment: What's the result of this data transformation, say if I have value.get("a").asText? I feel like I can't achieve my goal simply using this transformation.

Comment: @teddy In your example, you can use asInt() to get the value of the field. Also you can cast them into other format. Actually, the result of value.get() value is JsonNode, treat them as normal json objects.

Comment: I realized that too. But do you know how I can output this messgage to a downstream kafka? I have posted a question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45560112/error-in-sinking-kafka-stream-in-flink-1-2  I feel like flink makes it very hard to match the signature while calling sink API @David

Comment: @teddy Dawid answered your question minutes ago :)

Comment: Hi Dawid, if you are interested could you help me out in this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587789/how-to-extract-part-of-a-string-in-json-format-from-kafka-in-flink-1-2

Comment: It is a more detailed post than this one. Thanks! @Dawid