# Error in sinking kafka stream in flink 1.2

Tags: streaming, apache-flink

What I did was to read in a message from kafka in json format. E.g.

```
{"a":1,"b":2}
```

Then I applied a filter to this message to make sure the value corresponding to a is 1, the value of b is 2. Finally, I want to output the result stream to a downstream kafka. However, I don't know why the compiler says type mismatch.

My code is as follows:

```
val kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010(
params.getRequired("input-topic"),
new JSONDeserializationSchema(),
params.getProperties)

val messageStream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer).rebalance
val filteredStream: DataStream[ObjectNode] = messageStream.filter(jsonNode => jsonNode.get("a").asText.equals("1")
                      && jsonNode.get("b").asText.equals("2"))

filteredStream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer010[Object](params.getRequired("output-topic"), new SimpleStringSchema, params.getProperties))
```

The error I got is shown in the image below:
[image]

I refer to the flink kafka connector document to write the kafka outstream code:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/connectors/kafka.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stream `DataStream` of type `ObjectNode`, so you need to provide `FlinkKafkaProducer010[ObjectNode]` e.g:

```
stream1.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer010[ObjectNode](params.getRequired("output-topic"), new SerializationSchema[ObjectNode] {
  override def serialize(element: ObjectNode): Array[Byte] = ???
} ), params.getProperties)
```

All generic types in java are invariant in type, that is why you cannot just pass `FlinkKafkaProducer010[Object]`.

Another problem you may encounter further is that you also need to provide `SerializationSchema[ObjectNode]` whereas the `SimpleStringSchema` implements `SerializationSchema[String]`.

Comment: How can I provide FlinkKafkaProducer010[ObjectNode]?

Comment: Thanks a lot! My program compiles now. I replace your ??? by element.toString.getBytes(). However, I am not able to see any messge in my downstream kafka. Is there something wrong with what I wrote? @Dawid

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @Dawid already pointed out, you can provide the serialization schema for the ObjectNode (Assuming it's a POJO, as I haven't tested it for other objects) as follows:

```
TypeInformation<ObjectNode> typeInfo =
        TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<ObjectNode>() {});
TypeInformationSerializationSchema<ObjectNode> serdeSchema =
        new TypeInformationSerializationSchema<>(typeInfo, env.getConfig());
```

and then use *serdeschema* as follows for the KafkaPrducer sink:

```
FlinkKafkaProducer010<RecordReadEventType> kafkaSink =
                new FlinkKafkaProducer010<>(
                                BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
                                "output-topic",
                                serdeSchema);
```

Hopefully, this would solve your issues with kafka sink conflicts.

Comment: I've solved the conflict ( at least my program runs ). But there is no output stream. I feel like if I use JSONDeserializationSchema in the Kafka consumer (while reading in kafka message), my program cannot read in anything. I posted one more quesiton if you can help me out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564373/cannot-see-message-while-sinking-kafka-stream-and-cannot-see-print-message-in-fl