# Cannot see message while sinking kafka stream and cannot see print message in flink 1.2

Tags: streaming, apache-flink

My goal is to use kafka to read in a string in json format, do a filter to the string and then sink the message out (still in json string format).

For testing purpose, my input string message looks like:

```
{"a":1,"b":2}
```

And my code of implementation is:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

// parse input arguments
val params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args)

if (params.getNumberOfParameters < 4) {
  println("Missing parameters!\n"
    + "Usage: Kafka --input-topic <topic> --output-topic <topic> "
    + "--bootstrap.servers <kafka brokers> "
    + "--zookeeper.connect <zk quorum> --group.id <some id> [--prefix <prefix>]")
  return
}

val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.getConfig.disableSysoutLogging
env.getConfig.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(4, 10000))
// create a checkpoint every 5 seconds
env.enableCheckpointing(5000)
// make parameters available in the web interface
env.getConfig.setGlobalJobParameters(params)

// create a Kafka streaming source consumer for Kafka 0.10.x
val kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010(
  params.getRequired("input-topic"),
  new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false),
  params.getProperties)

val messageStream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer)

val filteredStream: DataStream[ObjectNode] = messageStream.filter(node => node.get("a").asText.equals("1")
                      && node.get("b").asText.equals("2"))

messageStream.print()
// Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/apache-flink/9004/how-to-define-a-custom-deserialization-schema#t=201708080802319255857
filteredStream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer010[ObjectNode](
  params.getRequired("output-topic"),
  new SerializationSchema[ObjectNode] {
    override def serialize(element: ObjectNode): Array[Byte] = element.toString.getBytes()
  }, params.getProperties
))

env.execute("Kafka 0.10 Example")
}
```

As can be seen, I want to print message stream to the console and sink the filtered message to kafka. However, I can see neither of them.

The interesting thing is, if I modify the schema of KafkaConsumer from JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema to SimpleStringSchema, I can see messageStream print to the console. Code as shown below:

```
 val kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010(
  params.getRequired("input-topic"),
  new SimpleStringSchema,
  params.getProperties)

val messageStream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer)
messageStream.print()
```

This makes me think if I use JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema, my input message is actually not accepted by Kafka. But this seems so weird and quite different from the online document(https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/connectors/kafka.html)

Hope someone can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema()* expects message key with each kafka msg and I am assuming that no key is supplied when the JSON messages are produced and sent over the kafka topic.

Thus to solve the issue, try using *JSONDeserializationSchema()* which expects only the message and creates an object node based on the message received.

Comment: I actually tried that before. My program will start without problem for about 30s, but still no output (both console and kafka). Then, I will get an error saying: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed. Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'PREFIX': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@68d8025; line: 1, column: 8]

Comment: Are you sure the JSON you are feeding is correct? because I ran your example with a sample code and it works at my end. Can you check your JSON for validity here : https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Yes, {"a":1,"b":2} is definitely a valid json ( I checked as well ). I wonder how do you test my code? What I did was to use a local kafka consumer for input, a local kafka producer for output. I am not able to see the output from flink program.

Comment: I sent the JSON over a kafka topic and used the JSONDeserializationSchema() to read from the kafka topic and then printed after adding the source to the execution environment. Are you using any specific Time Characteristics? I did something like this : https://pastebin.com/xzuK7YK6

Comment: I see the problem. If I test like what you did, then I did see the output. However, if I applied a filter (messageStream.filter), then I cannot see the output. Maybe there is some problem with the filter implementation.

Comment: From your original post, it looks you are printing the message stream and not the filtered stream. Because I saw you used, messageStream.print() rather than filteredstream.print() , so in the first case, it should simply print the results and not the filtered stream.

Comment: I solved my problem finally. It turns out that my kafka has accumulated lots of past data and when I output I can actually see lots of messages ( sometimes no message, I don't know why ). The way to solve my problem is to use a different topic name (both input and output) and use a different group ID. Finally I can do what I want, the reading kafka looks good, filter looks good and writing to downstream kafka looks good. I just have one more question left which is to select a specific key-value pair, I'll post another question then. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I understand you correctly then in your kafka configuration, your "auto.offset.reset" property is set to earliest/smallest (based on your kafka version), setting it to latest should solve the issue of reading old records from kafka. Its default value is latest, but you can explicitly set that value as well.

Comment: Where is "auto.offset.reset" property by the way? I searched server.properties and producer.properties file and cannot find it. I remember I read something similar in kafka document as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151474/discussion-between-biplob-biswas-and-teddy).